# Vuejs - external routes file

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a routes.js file

```
export default [{
      path: '/welcome',
      component: {
        template: `<div>
              <profile></profile>
              <user-info><user-info>
            </div>
                `
      }
    },
```

In my app.js

I import the routes and try and add them to the router

```
import routes from './routes/routes';

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});
```

However I get the error

```
app.js:1713 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <profile> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I am sure have used this technique before but maybe not with single file components. It is the .vue files causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register both components. Given your example you have three options:

1) Global registration:

```
import Profile from './Profile'
Vue.component('profile', Profile)

import UserInfo from './UserInfo'
Vue.component('user-info', UserInfo)

// routes import
// vue init
```

2) Local registration

```
import Profile from './Profile'
import UserInfo from './UserInfo'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Profile, UserInfo }

})
```

3) Register them directly in the route:

```
export default [{
    path: '/welcome',
    component: {
        template: `<div>
            <profile></profile>
            <user-info><user-info>
          </div>`,
          components: { Profile, UserInfo }
        },
    }
 }]);
```